# How do I get hyperlinks to play well with SpringBoot controller?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, hyperlink

I'm creating a simple website as a SpringBoot application. For some reason, the hyperlinks between various pages are not working. If I throw all the html docs in a folder and open with a browser, it seems to work fine, but the same files in the SpringBoot application don't seem to work. This causes me to suspect it may be the Controller, but I can't seem to find exactly what the issue is.

The documents themselves are all in the "templates" folder of the src/main/resources directory of the SB project (I'm using Eclipse). The home page "index.html" actually does work. But, none of the links to other pages work.

```java
package controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class VWDController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value="doityourself")
        public String doityourself() {
            return "doityourself";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value="viking")
        public String viking() {
            return "viking";
        }       
        @RequestMapping(value="enemy")
        public String enemy() {
            return "enemy";
        }   
        @RequestMapping(value="demopage")
        public String demopage() {
            return "demopage";


}
}
```

hyperlink code in the html docs:

```
Click <a href="demopage">here</a> 

online <a href="doityourself">presence.</a>
```

Updated code, post-suggestions from first two contributors (thanks!).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class VWDController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/") // This seems to work fine
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/doityourself")
    public String doityourself() {
        return "/doityourself"; // adding and removing
    } // the initial "/" has
    // no effect

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/viking")
    public String viking() {
        return "/viking";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/enemy")
    public String enemy() {
        return "/enemy";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/demopage")
    public String demopage() {
        return "/demopage";

    }
}
```

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/doityourself
Result: '/doityourself'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. However, these changes don't seem to change the behavior any. The index page still loads correctly, and the links still don't work. Current controller code:

Comment: package controller;        
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class VWDController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/")
  public String index() {
   return "index";
  }
   @RequestMapping(value="doityourself")
   public String doityourself() {
    return "doityourself";
   }
    @RequestMapping(value="viking")
    public String viking() {
     return "viking";
    }  
   
}

Comment: Sorry, that formatting is a mess. SO not very user-friendly in that regard. I'll fix it.

Comment: Ok, so newlines are not possible in comments, making code impractical to place there.

Comment: Allright, so I've updated the code, implementing the suggestions from Bor Laze and Ilya Serebryannikov.  This still doesn't work though. Index page still comes up fine, and White Label Error page for all the others. The initial "/" in the hyperlink doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This code incites the "declared package does not match expected package controller" message. The message can be removed by adding the "package controller;" declaration. However, the links still do not work in either case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove slash in your return statements
2. In your link use your endpoints, not HTML files.

`Click <a href="/demopage">here</a>`